# ImportError when attempting to mock a module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a module that I am testing that depends on another module that won't be available at the time of testing.  To get around this, I wrote (essentially):

```
import mock
import sys

sys.modules['parent_module.unavailable_module'] = mock.MagicMock()
import module_under_test
```

This works fine as long as `module_under_test` is doing one of the following `import parent_module`, `import parent_module.unavailable_module`.  However, the following code generates a traceback:

```
>>> from parent_module import unavailable_module
ImportError: cannot import name unavailable_module
```

What's up with this?  What can I do in my test code (without changing the import statement) to avoid this error?

Comment: I am not using mock.patch because that requires 'unavailable_module' to already be imported.

Comment: By the way - the fact that I had to do this was a sign of bad design in the code under test. The code that necessitated this bludgeoning is now under test, and so I was able to modify it to make this unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I think I've figured it out.  It appears that in the statement:

```
from parent_module import unavailable_module
```

Python looks for an *attribute* of `parent_module` called `unavailable_module`.  Therefore, the following set up code fully replaces `unavailable_module` within `parent_module`:

```
import mock
import sys

fake_module = mock.MagicMock()
sys.modules['parent_module.unavailable_module'] = fake_module
setattr(parent_module, 'unavailable_module', fake_module)
```

I tested the four import idioms of which I am aware:

```
import parent_module
import parent_module.unavailable_module
import parent_module.unavailable_module as unavailabe_module
from parent_module import unavailable_module
```

and each worked with the above set up code.